# Import changes from selected schematics not all in Altium

Tags: altium

At the start please note that I'm new in Altium.
 I'm having 7 schematics and 2 pcb documents. For first document I want to import changes only from 1,2 and 3 schematics, but if i go to `Design->Import changes from project_name` I only can import from all project schematics and I have a list of unused items to choose.This situation causes that i need to slide up the list and search needed element and finding element is longer. If anyone knows the answer, I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: There's no way of doing that. Instead, create seperate projects for each PCB and relevant schematics, and group the projects under a workspace. Re-enumerat the components with 100-199 for PCB1, 200-299 for PCB2 and so forth. Easier to manage.

Comment: Thanks for answer :)